Null cluster workload name when querying for compute engine cost
When querying for Compute Engine costs I get one record with a null workload name.
What services besides k8s consume Compute Engine or maybe there is an unnamed workload in k8s?
How do I further investigate this cost?
SELECT
  DATE(usage_start_time) day,
  ROUND(SUM(cost),2) AS sum_cost,
  labels.value AS workload,
FROM
  my_billing_table
LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(labels) AS labels
ON
  labels.key = "k8s-workload-name"
WHERE
  DATE(usage_start_time) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL -2 DAY)
  AND DATE(partition_time) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL -2 DAY)
  AND project.name = 'my_project'
  AND service.description = 'Compute Engine'
GROUP BY
  1,
  3
ORDER BY
  1 DESC

